# shaka player never triggers 'error' listener

Tags: javascript, html, media-player, video-player, shaka

I am integrating shaka player in my web application. I have gone throught the documentation and found basic program to load player with video manifest url. Link for basic program is [basic tutorial](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/tutorial-basic-usage.html). And it is loading video fine.

I need to implement error handing for player. So I am trying to understand, where the 'error' event listener will be firing. Following is the code for listening error. It is not triggering anymore for me.

```
 // Listen for error events.
  player.addEventListener('error', onErrorEvent);
```

Following are the Trails to get it invoked but not triggered:
Trail 1: Not initialized video variable.

```
  const video = null;
  const player = new shaka.Player(video);
```

Trail 2: Loading an invalid manifest url.

```
try {
    await player.load('https://mydymmy.manifest.url');
  } catch (e) {
    onError(e);
  }
```

I would like to implement error handling in my program. For that i need to understand when this 'error' listener will be invoking.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I ran into this issue too and to help anyone else who runs into this issue, this is how you catch the error on load.

```
await player.load('https://mydymmy.manifest.url').catch(onError);
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30985349)

Answer (score 0):

player.addEventListener('error', onErrorEvent);

The listener example in the tutorial didn't work

---

const listener = new shaka.util.EventManager();

listener.listen(player, `error`, (event: any) => {
onErrorEvent(event);
});

[You should use shaka.util.EventManager](https://shaka-player-demo.appspot.com/docs/api/shaka.util.EventManager.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).